# How do I set the margin between each element in CSS?

Tags: css, margin, element

I am trying to do this in css:

**The margin between each element is 10px
The textarea height is 100px and the width is 150px**

This is some of my html code for reference:

```css
main form label {
  margin: 10px;
}

textarea {
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <label>
            First name:
            <input type="text" name="firstname">
        </label>
        <label>
            Last name:
            <input type="text" name="lastname">
        </label>
        <label>
            Email:
            <input type="text" name="email">
        </label>
        <label>
            Select Your State:
            <select>
                <option value="florida">Florida</option>
                <option value="california">California</option>
                <option value="michigan" selected="selected">Michigan</option>
                <option value="new york">New York</option>
                <option value="texas">Texas</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <label>
            Male
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">
        </label>
        <label>
            Female
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">
        </label>
        <label>
            Comment:
            <textarea name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
        </label>
        <input type='submit' value='Submit' />

    </form>

</main>
```

I am not sure why it isnt working. I have done regular margins before. I just don't know how to make margins between **ALL** elements.

Comment: Are toy trying to get the `label` elements spaced out by 10 pixels one after the other on new lines or next to each other in a row?

Comment: `<label>` elements are `display: inline;` by default, meaning they'll only obey horizontal margins. Add `display: inline-block;` or `display: block;` (depending on whether you want the items to be on new lines) to `main form label { ... }` alongside your margins.

Comment: thanks! display: block worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Inline elements ignore vertical margin. Use `inline-block`.

```css
main form label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

textarea {
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <label>
            First name:
            <input type="text" name="firstname">
        </label>
        <label>
            Last name:
            <input type="text" name="lastname">
        </label>
        <label>
            Email:
            <input type="text" name="email">
        </label>
        <label>
            Select Your State:
            <select>
                <option value="florida">Florida</option>
                <option value="california">California</option>
                <option value="michigan" selected="selected">Michigan</option>
                <option value="new york">New York</option>
                <option value="texas">Texas</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <label>
            Male
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">
        </label>
        <label>
            Female
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">
        </label>
        <label>
            Comment:
            <textarea name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
        </label>
        <input type='submit' value='Submit' />

    </form>

</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the label to `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;`.

```
main form label {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Labels are displayed inline by default and therefore the margin value does not apply as you probably expect. Maybe this helps you to understand the issue: http://maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/